# How to Get All records with specific Id and LastDate

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

this is my table
I'm using .Net 3.1 and EFcore.

I have a controller with an input `int[] TermIds` which contains on or more `TermId`.

Now I want to select All records which their `TermId` exist In `TemrIds` AND their `statisticDate` is the latest date.

Note that Maximum Date for each TermId is Different from others

```
| Id    | TermID |UniversityId|StatisticDate|FileTypeId|Count|
| :----:| :-----:|:---------: |:------------|:--------:|:----|
|  1    |126     |5           |2012/01/10   |4         |150  |
|  2    |126     |5           |2012/01/10   |3         |250  |
|  3    |126     |4           |2012/01/10   |4         |127  |
|  4    |126     |4           |2012/01/10   |3         |110  |
|  5    |126     |5           |2011/01/10   |4         |107  |
|  6    |126     |5           |2011/01/10   |3         |99   |
|  7    |126     |4           |2011/01/10   |4         |103  |
|  8    |126     |4           |2011/01/10   |3         |96   |
|  9    |123     |5           |2011/01/01   |4         |88   |
|  10   |123     |5           |2011/01/01   |3         |76   |
|  11   |123     |4           |2011/01/01   |4         |98   |
|  12   |123     |4           |2011/01/01   |3         |99   |
|  13   |123     |5           |2010/01/01   |4         |77   |
|  14   |123     |5           |2010/01/01   |3         |66   |
|  15   |123     |4           |2010/01/01   |4         |33   |
|  16   |123     |4           |2010/01/01   |3         |55   |
```

and at last i want this records

```
| Id    | TermID |UniversityId|StatisticDate|FileTypeId|Count|
| :----:| :-----:|:---------: |:------------|:--------:|:----|
|  1    |126     |5           |2012/01/10   |4         |150  |
|  2    |126     |5           |2012/01/10   |3         |250  |
|  3    |126     |4           |2012/01/10   |4         |127  |
|  4    |126     |4           |2012/01/10   |3         |110  |
|  9    |123     |5           |2011/01/01   |4         |88   |
|  10   |123     |5           |2011/01/01   |3         |76   |
|  11   |123     |4           |2011/01/01   |4         |98   |
|  12   |123     |4           |2011/01/01   |3         |99   |
```

Comment: look at the table,for TermId 126 the last date is 2012/01/10 But for TermId 123 the last date is 2011/01/01.now I want (for example) all records with (TermId=123  and the statisticDate =2011/01/01) which is the largest date for all 123TermId's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linq query I can think of based on my understanding. This should only filter out the records that have `TermID` existing on the `termIds` and the `StatisticDate` is the maximum date per term.

```
        using System.Linq;

        int[] termIds = new int[] { 126, 127 };

        List<Foo> data = new List<Foo>()
        {
            new Foo() { Id = 1, TermID = 126, UniversityId = 5, StatisticDate = new DateTime(2012, 01, 10), FileTypeId = 4, Count = 150 },
            new Foo() { Id = 2, TermID = 126, UniversityId = 5, StatisticDate = new DateTime(2012, 01, 10), FileTypeId = 3, Count = 250 },
            new Foo() { Id = 3, TermID = 126, UniversityId = 4, StatisticDate = new DateTime(2012, 01, 10), FileTypeId = 4, Count = 127 },
            new Foo() { Id = 4, TermID = 126, UniversityId = 4, StatisticDate = new DateTime(2012, 01, 10), FileTypeId = 3, Count = 110 },
            new Foo() { Id = 5, TermID = 126, UniversityId = 5, StatisticDate = new DateTime(2011, 01, 10), FileTypeId = 4, Count = 107 },
        };

        var records = data.Where(r => termIds.Contains(r.TermID) && r.StatisticDate == data.Where(x => x.TermID == r.TermID).Max(x => x.StatisticDate));
```

Comment: yes jegtugado thanks alot.this is exactly what i want